# WebAssembly/emscripten: write files to disk from within browser

Tags: javascript, fs, emscripten, webassembly

I have some C code I would like to execute in a Browser (testing with Firefox 64.0). The C code writes a file to disk.

I have been trying to use the emscripten's File System API for many many hours now and I am getting nowhere.

I have read this [relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15056752/emscripten-using-filesystem-fs) and the [emscripten doc](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/api_reference/Filesystem-API.html) states the same:

- if your C/C++ code does use files, then file system support will be automatically included.

Here is my test code which uses the file system:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  FILE *f = fopen("testfile.txt", "w");
  if (f == NULL) {
      printf("Error opening file!\n");
      exit(1);
  }

  const char *text = "This is my test string";
  int i = 1234;
  fprintf(f, "Some text: %s; and an int: %d\n", text, i);

  fclose(f);
  printf("End of file.\n");
}
```

After I compiled this code with:

```
emcc test.c -o test.html
```

And opening it with Firefox, I initially expected the file to be saved onto my machine. (I have no JS background.)
I am now almost certain that it does not work like that.

The file is accessible as Uint8Array via:

```
var array = FS.readfile("testfile.txt")
```

in the console.

Specifically, I am now interested in this:

1. Is there a way to write a file to my local filesystem from inside the browser?
2. Can I download the created file in some way?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Using JavaScript, you can set up a download link and initiate a traditional file download. SO has lots of answers related to how to do that with JavaScript. For instance, here is one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32562347/how-to-download-a-file-generated-with-javascript-avoiding-automatic-opening-of

Comment: You can not write a file to the user's machine the browser from JavaScript nor WebAssembly. You can offer the user a file to download. You can save data in IndexedDB. You can upload the data to a server. But, you can not just write files, at least as of January 2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR; **Never expect you could write anything in your machine on a browser.**

Modern web browsers are designed with security in mind so they are highly sandboxed. They are never going to allow web pages to write/open a local file in your machine. Imagine someone visit your website and then a file called `testfile.txt` is created in their machine, and the website keeps creating files every time you press the refresh button.

WebAssembly has no exception. It is just a virtual machine to run code written in languages other than Javascript. Keep in mind that WebAssembly is run by a JavaScript engine. So saying "I have no JS background." is simply an invalid statement. What JS can't do is what WebAssembly can't.

According to the [Emscripten File System Overview](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/files/file_systems_overview.html) documentation, the **files you create will stay in the memory.** You have to convert it to Blob (this has to be done using JavaScript API) to allow users to download.

Comment: This: _never going to allow web pages to open a local file in your machine_. This is misleading at best and inaccurate at worst. Please consider rewording to take into account the JavaScript [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)

Comment: @RandyCasburn not quite the same thing. The difference being that the user has explicitly granted the browser access to a particular file via a `<input type="file">` element, whereas the question is about accessing a file on disk with a specific name.

Comment: Sure, I understand the difference, but your statement is direct "never going to allow" is not true given user interaction - at which time the browser reads a local file in your machine. It is mincing words, but may mislead someone in the future while reading your answer.